# how to set value dynamically created textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

---

I'm using javascript to dynamically generate a dialogue box (it's a div element), containing a textbox .
THE PROBLEM: I can generate my textbox just fine, but I can't get the value from it. innerHTML comes back blank every time. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
            var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
            var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newTBDiv.setAttribute('id', 'strText' + intTextBox);
            newTBDiv.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(64 + (intTextBox + 2)) + ' :' 
                   + "<input style='margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;width: 250px;'"
                   + " class='txt3_double' type='text' id='" 
                   + intTextBox + "' name='" + intTextBox 
                   + "' placeholder='Next Location Point'/>"
                   + "<img src='img/Add.png' onclick='addElement();return false;' />"
                   + "<img src='img/Minus.png' onclick='removeElement();return false;' />";
            contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
            textboxes = intTextBox;

            TextBoxloc = TextBoxloc + 1;
            var contentIDloc = document.getElementById('content');
            var newTBDivloc = document.createElement('div');
            newTBDivloc.setAttribute('id', 'strText' + TextBoxloc);
            newTBDivloc.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(64 + (TextBoxloc + 2)) 
                       + ' :' + "<input class='txt3_double' type='text' id='" 
                       + TextBoxloc + "' name='" + TextBoxloc + "' />";
            contentIDloc.appendChild(newTBDivloc);
            textboxesloc = TextBoxloc ;

            $(document.getElementById(intTextBox)).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    debugger
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Root.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData") %>',
                        data: "{ 'Address': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d.length == 0) {
                                $('.ui-autocomplete').hide();
                            }
                            else {
                                $(".pac-container").remove();
                                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                    debugger
                                    return {
                                        label: item.split('-')[0],
                                        val: item.split('-')[1],
                                        long: item.split('-')[2]
                                    }
                                }))
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },

                select: function (e, i) {
                    debugger
                    document.getElementById(TextBoxloc).value = i.item.val;
                },
                minLength: 2

            });
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the problem? I'm not reading all of that when I don't need to.

Comment: If you are already using jquery, why not use it to generate the textfield without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I can see where you're creating individual textboxes with unique ids coming from intTextBox, so to get at the text in the textboxes just use the value:

```js
var textboxVal = $(intTextBox).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

document.getElementById(TextBoxloc).value = i.item.value;

**i.item.val should be i.item.value**

Answer (score 0):

I see you are adding "strText" in id attribute and trying to set the value using

```
document.getElementById(TextBoxloc).value = i.item.val;
```

and are you getting the right value in i.item.val??

good luck...

Comment: Yes i getting the right value in i.item.val.

document.getElementById(TextBoxloc).value = i.item.val;
It's not working.

Comment: Did you try document.getElementById("strText" + TextBoxloc).value = i.item.val;